# Android app not working in emulator

Tags: android

I have made an android app which is working fine in my device but when i run it on emulator then app crashes.

My logcat is:

```
08-19 07:09:46.497: ERROR/ActivityThread(768): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf4668 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf4668 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-19 07:09:46.497: ERROR/StrictMode(768): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf4668 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have also make new AVD and then run the app but i am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you give the code of the activity that gives you this error. is the activity added in the manifest file ?

Comment: yes that activity is added in manifest file

Answer (score 2):

```
    Try Creating New AVD 
    OR
    I had the same issue, and solved it by removing the "use host GPU" option
    OR
    Disable "Exchange Services" in the emulated device under Settings ->Apps -> All
```